# Algolia - get mass records & delete with filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, algolia

I am using Algolia for search purposes and we got a huge pile of records. We want to delete some records and have decided to delete records that are older than X date.

First I was using this

```js
const records = [];
const deleteRecordsBeforeDateAlgolia = (date) => {
    let client;

    *****

    const index = client.initIndex('function_message');
    //get the records before the given date
    try {
        index.search('',{
            filters: `time_stamp < ${date}`
        }).then(({hits}) => {
            if(hits.length > 0) {
                for (const hit of hits) {
                    index.deleteObject(hit.objectID);
                    records.push(hit.objectID);
                }
            }
            if(hits.length === 0) {
                console.log(`Deleted ${records.length} records`);
            } else {
                deleteRecordsBeforeDateAlgolia(date);
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

but I realized this isnt that optimized + will be very slow when deleting on prod. Can you tell me how I can get huge amounts of data with a filter (timestamp in this case) and then delete all of them?

## EDIT

```js
const records = [];
const deleteRecordsBeforeDateAlgolia = (date) => {
    let client;

    //creds stuff


    const index = client.initIndex('function_message');
    //get the records before the given date
    try {
        const search =  index.browseObjects({
            filters: `time_stamp < ${date}`
        }).then(res => {
            //IT SHOWS RESPONSE IS UNDEFINED
            res.forEach(record => {
                records.push(record);
            });
            console.log(`found ${records.length} records`);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: you can  do bulk delete with `deleteObjects`. btw why not use async await.

Comment: wanted it to be synchronous thats why (i know the code is quite bad)

Comment: yeah what i was thinkinh with async  await was something like `const hits = await index.search....` and then `idArray = hits.map...` to return an array of `objectID` and then `await deleteObjects(idArray)`

Comment: the problem is, index.search will only result 20 results AT MAX.

Comment: have you tried the same thing in your current implementation instead of the for loop. map the hits and get id array and then do deleteObjects

Comment: How many records are you looking to retrieve? For a large number, you may be better off doings a "[browse](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/browse/?client=javascript)" than a "search", then pairing that with deleteObjects as @cmgchess recommends above.

Comment: @ChuckMeyer browse doesnt let me apply filters, or if it does, can you show how to?

Comment: @VineshRajpurohit didnt something like this work `index.browseObjects({
  query: '',
  filters: 'updated_at>1641905859',
  batch: batch => {......`

Comment: Check the edit please @cmgchess

Comment: @VineshRajpurohit try adding an empty query with `query: ''` and in the `batch` funtion  you can do the pushing. this example https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/browse/?client=javascript#browse-an-index-recommended-way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`browseObjects`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/browse/?client=javascript#browse-an-index-recommended-way) takes a batch callback function that's called on every batch of hits where you can specify what to do with the batch. The optional parameter list can be found [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/browse/?client=javascript#parameters)

Something like this should work

```js
const records = [];

const deleteFromIndex = (idArray,index) => {
    index.deleteObjects(idArray).then(({ objectIDs }) => {
        console.log(objectIDs);
    });
}


const deleteRecordsBeforeDateAlgolia = (date) => {
  let client;
  client = algoliasearch('algoliaApp', 'algoliaKey');

  const index = client.initIndex('function_message');
  try {
    index.browseObjects({
        filters: `time_stamp<${date}`,
        query: '',
        batch: (batch) => {       
          records.push(...batch);  //push each batch into records array
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        const idArray = records.map(({objectID}) => objectID) //get an array of objectIDs
        deleteFromIndex(idArray, index)
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

deleteRecordsBeforeDateAlgolia('some date')
```